# iptables with docker blocking incoming traffic, allowing outgoing traffic

Tags: docker, iptables

I'm running a dockerized app on an ubuntu machine. It's a test environment so I want to limit acces to a few IP addresses. I use the following iptables rules:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -p tcp --dport 443 -j REJECT
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -p tcp --dport 3306 -j REJECT
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -s <my ip> -p tcp --dport 443 -j RETURN
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -s 172.18.0.0/16 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j RETURN
```

Works ok to block all traffic, except it also blocks all outgoing traffic, rendering e.g. api-calls to other systems useless. How can I block all incoming traffic on 443, and also allow outgoing traffic on 443?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify rules for the DOCKER-USER chain targeting  the docker interface with `-i` as input and `-o` as output.

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i ${docker_interface} -p tcp --dport 443 -j REJECT
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -o ${docker_interface} -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

instead of :

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -p tcp --dport 443 -j REJECT
```

If you're running your docker container with default bridged configuration, the `${docker_interface}` should be set with `bridge`. If it is not the case, use the `docker network ls` command to retrieve it.

Comment: Thanks, that helps! Small change: I needed to put the hosts network interface instead of 'bridge'. Then it works as intentend.

Comment: @Lennart I get it, your goal was to filter tcp traffic outside the docker container (on the host), not inside. Maybe you should precise that in the body of the question ?